# How to extend the current theme with custom scopes in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension for Visual Studio Code where I also want to add coloring for a language. However, I'd need more scopes than what is usually defined in a theme file. Of course I could also create an own theme to add what I need (via a [themes contribution point](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesthemes)), but that's not very user friendly. It would be better if I could just append new scopes to colorize to the existing theme via my extension.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: It is a shame this didn't get any responses. I was just thinking the same thing and my search brought me here. I was thinking that if the colors are basically set via a style it should be possible to add a css or json extension point to add additional styles. What I would like to do is to define a "default" style for my language and allow a theme to override my styles.

Comment: Related: [How to customize the color of custom syntax tokens in VSCode extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377151/how-to-customize-the-color-of-custom-syntax-tokens-in-vscode-extension).