# How to customize color of HTML template props in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Inspecting the mustache content in the below code with [Developer: Inspect TM scopes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_new-tools-for-inspecting-textmate-scopes)

```
<p>name: {{ name }}</p>
```

I get `text.html.basic`, meaning there is no separate scope for changing the color of `name` inside the mustache tags. Is there any other way of changing the color of template props in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't find a better way with scopes, you could try the [highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight).

And this setting seems to work:

```
"highlight.regexes": {

    "({{[/!^>#]*\\s*)([^}]+)(\\s*}})": [
         {},  // first match group "{{" gets no color, must be here
         {
            // "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00",
            "color": "#f00",
            // "fontWeight": "bold"
         },
         {} // third match group "}}" gets no color, does not need to be here
     ],
}
```

[image: example of mustache syntax highlighting]

Comment: Edit : changed the regex so the desired capture of the template props is better and updated the image example.

Comment: i think youre missing a `)` in the middle. the way you wrote it might as well take out the 3rd pattern. heres one for angular prop binding: `"(\\s+\\[[\\w-]+\\]=\"[/!^>#]*)([^\"]+)"`

Comment: You are right on your comments, a typo by me on the regex, and the last match group doesn't need to be included if you are doing nothing with it.