# Customize color of text inside `backquotes` in VSCode

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

The only options I can find that deal with custom coloring inside Visual Studio Code are those:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Atom One Dark]": {
        "comments": "#FF0000" // only 6 color-customizable
    },
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "statusBar.background": "#666666",
        "panel.background": "#555555",
        "sideBar.background": "#444444"
    },
},
```

Is there a way to set a custom color for these types of things? One exists for comments, for strings (inside `"string"`). I believe something similar should be possible for other stuff using regexps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Search for `tokenColorCustomizations` and `textMateRules` and you will find that you can do something like this (see [colorizing with textmate](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules)):

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

    "textMateRules": [
      {
            // works for a language that recognizes backticks as string templates
        "scope": "string.template",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#FF0000"
        }
      },
      {
       "scope": "punctuation.definition.template-expression.begin, punctuation.definition.template-expression.end",
       "settings": {
         "foreground": "#F0F"
       }
      },
    ]
}
```

using the `Inspect TM Scopes...` command in the command palette.  So I used that command to click inside a template literal and got the `string.template.js.jsx` scope. But that didn't change the ${someVar} so I inspected that scope and saw  `variable.other.readwrite.js.jsx` plus additional scope parameters - still working on isolating that kind of a variable from other variables.

Edit:  Should work in more file types by using only `string.template`, if the language treats backticks as a string template.

You can also change the `fontStyle` within a setting.  There are a few answers here about using the `TM Scopes` command.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Doesn't work for backticks and I can't find anything suitable for that right now. Will have to check again.

Comment: I modified it some, I had it for .ts files, are you in .js or .jsx?  Then the answer should work for the backticks and the text inside.  Hwever, a ${somevar} isn't getting colored by that and needs more investigation.  But perhaps the amended answer is sufficient?

Comment: No, no I never said I'm in `.js` or any particular language. I actually want it enabled globally, It shouldn't be a problem to change the scope of the language though right?

Comment: I think you would have to make an entry for each anticipated scope though.  There is an alternative hack that would apply to all languages, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717380/how-to-customize-color-of-html-template-props-in-visual-studio-code/52733363#52733363 something I worked out for handlebars {{ }} like languages syntax highlighting.  It is a hack but works well.