# How can I inject a custom color to an existing coding language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I´m currently developing a AL language extension for inline code documentation.

I already created a grammar file that defines start and end regions of documenation blocks.

```
{
  "scopeName": "al.custom",
  "injectionSelector": "L:comment.block.al.one",
  "patterns": [
    { "include": "#doc-start" },
    { "include": "#doc-end" }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "doc-start": {
      "match": "^\\s*doc\\s*$",
      "name": "doc.start"
    },
    "doc-end": {
      "match": "^\\s*docend\\s*$",
      "name": "doc.end"
    }
  }
}
```

As said it´s injected (should add to the existing grammar) so I put it into the package.json contributes section:

```
"grammars": [
  {
    "path": "./syntaxes/al-grammar.json",
    "scopeName": "al.custom",
    "injectTo": ["source.al"]
  } ]
```

How can I apply a custom color to the scopes doc.start and doc.end?

Comment: I don't think you can "inject" colors, colors are handled by themes. There's a `tokenColorCustomizations` setting, but that's something to be specified by users, not extension. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785989/customize-color-of-text-inside-backquotes-in-vscode)

Comment: So can I apply a custom theme to the already existing one? How would that be done without overwriting the AL theme?