# Syntax coloring VSCode extension

Tags: syntax, vscode-extensions, textmate

I am trying to make an extension and need to colorize syntax for custom language. I was able to create extension using yo code and edit .tmLanguage.json file to match wanted syntaxes.
As for example in repository

```
"comment": {
  "patterns": [
    {
      "name": "comment.line.semicolon",
      "match": ";.*$"
    }
  ]
},
```

However i have not been able to set custom color. Only way was to edit settings.json file using "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" and providing textMateRules.
Example:
For the pattern:

```
{
      "name": "positioning.FMAX",
      "match": "\\bFMAX\\b"
    },
```

textMateRules

```
{
      "name": "color.positioning.FMAX",
      "scope": "positioning.FMAX",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#ff0000",
        "fontStyle": "bold"
      }
    },
```

But this is not working when i hit F5 to test plugin. Because settings.json is not part of the extension.
I see in scope inspector.

```
textmate scopes positioning.FMAX
```

but foreground is

```
foreground  No theme selector
```

comment.line.semicolon is working and coloring ;comments green

This doesn't work

```
{
      "name": "positioning.FMAX",
      "match": "\\bFMAX\\b",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#ff0000"
      }
 }
```

I just want simple way to color syntax like in setting.json. I have tried for more than week now. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I found answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377151/how-to-customize-the-color-of-custom-syntax-tokens-in-vscode-extension

Answer (score 0):

look at vscode-extension-samples repo:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/theme-sample

You can describe your colors in `json` or `tmTheme` file and set it in package.json in `contributes.themes`. When debbugging started make sure that your custom theme selected as current for VSCode