# Change json key color in Visual Studio Code depending on indentation level

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have updated my settings.json file in VS Code like so:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope":"support.type.property-name.json.comments",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000",
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

This results in all keys in my json files to be coloured red like so:

[image: How it looks in VS Code]

Ideally, I would like to configure it so that each key has a different colour depending on indentation level instead of everything being red, however after diving into the documentation, I am unsure how to approach this, and would like to know how it could be done.

Comment: indentation level... that on is not mentioned here: [How to customize the color of custom syntax tokens in VSCode extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377151/how-to-customize-the-color-of-custom-syntax-tokens-in-vscode-extension), you might need to [Crete your ow theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme) but my guess is that `indentation level` is not supported.

Comment: @Luuk a theme use the TextMate scopes found by the TextMate Language Grammar, JSON does not use indentation so its scopes are not marked in any way for this.

Comment: you can use the extension Highlight to mark certain parts of the file, it will handle indentation if it is part of the regex for the matching text, make a capture group of the property name and only color that group